# Why won't this javascript parse?

Tags: javascript, parsing, mailchimp

I seem to have everything in place,

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mailing-list.js"></script>
```

In the header, and `mailing-list.js` in the js folder. Yet for some reason, it does not seem to parse. I've pasted the code inline below - any ideas?

```
var emailEntered,
nameVal,
compVal,
foneVal,
cityVal,

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#SendButton").click(function () {
        $(".error").hide();
        var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
        var emailaddressVal = $("#email").val();

        if (emailaddressVal == '') {
            $("#message").html('<span class="error">Enter your email address before submitting.</span>');
            return false;
        } else if (!emailReg.test(emailaddressVal)) {
            $("#message").html("<span class='error'>That is not an email address.&nbsp;  Typo?</span>");
            return false;
        } else {
            emailEntered = escape($('#email').val());
        }

        nameVal = escape($("#name").val());
        emailVal = escape($("#email").val());
        compVal = escape($("#comp").val());
        foneVal = escape($("#fone").val());
        cityVal = escape($("#city").val());
    });
    $('#signup').submit(function () {
        $("#message").html("<span class='error'>Adding your email address...</span>");
        $.ajax({
            url: 'inc/store-address.php',
            data: 'ajax=true&email=' + emailEntered + '&name=' + nameVal + '&comp=' + compVal + '&fone=' + foneVal + '&city=' + cityVal,
            success: function (msg) {
                $('#message').html(msg);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Update: By parsing I mean the  call for mailing-list.js is being ignored.

Comment: What does "does not seem to parse" mean? What happens? What errors are you getting?

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't parse"? What are the errors?

Comment: By parsing I mean the <script> call for mailing-list.js is being ignored.

Comment: Use the built-in developer console. It's there to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var emailEntered,
    nameVal,
    compVal,
    foneVal,
    cityVal,
```

Should be:

```
var emailEntered,
    nameVal,
    compVal,
    foneVal,
    cityVal;
```

Notice the semicolon at the end.

Comment: also, those variable declarations really ought to be inside the anonymous function declaration.

Comment: what is the anonymous function declaration, Alnitak?

Comment: in JS all variables' scopes are local to a `function() {}` block. If you want to declare some variables, don't declare them at file level, where they will be globals, but inside the function, and the closer to where you use them.

Answer (score 2):

you should run a static code analyser on the code, like [jshint](http://jshint.com), while writing your code:

```
test.js: line 7, col 6, Missing semicolon.
test.js: line 13, col 36, Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.
```

you'll first see a few syntactic mistakes. Then, you should open your javascript console and look at what the error are. Usually the interpreter gives a lot of informations.

And by the way, the second warning is not really an error, but a good habit to have in javascript when doing equality checkings.

About your edit, you should use a script like firebug (or any other webdev tool you can get in your favorite browser) and check if it can get the script you're writing. 
Is it returning a 404? then check the path. Is it returning a 403? then check the permissions...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by "not parse" but you should check the developer console (look on your browser's menu).
And also :

```
 var emailEntered,
        nameVal,
        compVal,
        foneVal,
        cityVal,
```

Should be :

```
 var emailEntered,
        nameVal,
        compVal,
        foneVal,
        cityVal;
```